# p:textEditor : default value <p> <br> </p>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, text-editor

I use the PrimeFaces' textEditor component and a String variable (JEE) contains the text entered.
When I initialize this variable with "null" or "" just before calling the component, this variable then contains: `<p><br></p>`
As a result the placeholder is not displayed and the cursor is positioned on a second line.
How can I delete this value?

Here is my code:

```
    <p:contextMenu>
                <p:menuitem value="Ajouter une note" actionListener="#{noteManagerBean.initialiserNote()}" 
                            oncomplete="PF('widgetNoteDialog').show()" 
                            update="idNoteDialog"/>
            </p:contextMenu>

            <p:dialog id="idNoteDialog" widgetVar="widgetNoteDialog" style="position: absolute; border: none; border-radius: 0; z-index: 2" class="effetZoom" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" closable="false" resizable="false"> 
                <p:textEditor placeholder="Entrez votre texte ici" value="#{noteManagerBean.noteTexte}" height="129" style="width: 294px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 12px; margin-left: -1px; background-color: transparent">
                    <f:facet name="toolbar"> 
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                            <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                            <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                        </span>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:textEditor>
</p:dialog>
```

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class NoteManagerBean implements Serializable {

    private String noteTexte;

    public void initialiserNote() {

        setNoteTexte(null);

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Do you need to initialize your `noteTexte` variable? Also you could try with `setNoteTexte(new String())`.

Comment: I tried setNoteText(new String ()) but it does not work either

Comment: When I navigate between the pages of my project, the textEditor becomes null!
I'm having too many problems and I'm losing so much time with textEditor.
Is it advisable not to use this component?
What other solution do you recommend?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is related to the fix for this issue:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3170

Its trying to determine whether the Editor is already showing HTML or not.

```
getEditorValue: function() {
        var html = $(this.editorContainer[0]).find('p').text();
        var value = (html == '<p><br></p>') ? '' : html;

        return value;
    },
```

Comment: Please, can you give me an example of use ? Thank you very much.

Comment: The only other thing you can try if you are really having trouble with TextEditor is CKEditor from PrimeFaces Extensions found here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/customToolbar.jsf